# Does Taylor theorem apply in zero diagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, integration, taylor-expansion, hessian-matrix, matrix-norms

Let $H \stackrel{\Delta}{=} \nabla^2f(x)$ with $\|H(x) -H(y) \| \leq L \|x-y \|$ and let $D \stackrel{\Delta}{=} \text{diag} (H_{11},H_{22}, \dots, H_{dd})$. Then, $H$ can be written as $H \stackrel{\Delta}{=} A - D$, where $A$ is $H$ with the diagonal entries set to zero. Now I know from Taylor's Theorem [Theorem 2.1, [here](http://www.apmath.spbu.ru/cnsa/pdf/monograf/Numerical_Optimization2006.pdf)] that

$$\int_{0}^{1}H(x+ty)y\:dt = \nabla f(x+y) - \nabla f(y) \tag{1}$$

and I want to compute

$$\int_{0}^{1}\|A(x+ty)y\|\:dt. \tag{2}$$

I convenient result for me is to be zero or upper bounded by some quantity $C\|y\|^2$ but maybe this is not the case. So can you please someone provide some details on how we compute or upper bound $(1)$?

Comment: I don’t know what matrix Taylor series theorem you are using, but check the hypotheses closely. I highly doubt that having all zeroes on the diagonal is an obstruction

Comment: @FShrike I have added some more details. The hypothesis is to have $f$ twice continuously differentiable but it is not clear to me how this can be used in $A$.